# How to connect NodeJS with ReactJS front-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express

I am new to reactJS. I am working on project which uses following :

Front-end : **ReactJS**

Backend : **NodeJS** (Express)

Front-end runs on port 3000
Back-end runs on port 8088.

I am planning to deploy application on amazon AWS.

What i am trying to do is load reactJS front-end when i make request on http://localhost:8088/

I know using axios we can make request on backend server and display fetched data.

What would be standard way of loading ReactJS front from the nodeJS ?

Comment: You need a tutorial ,look for some online resources

Comment: I recommand to see this video by Brad Traversy.
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0t42xBIYIs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but generally in development you use something called proxy in your package.json in the client (react) folder:

```
{
  // Other stuff
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8088"
}
```

and then when you'd want to deploy you'd run `npm build` for your react folder and serve that generated folder called build. But as I said, you usually do that only when deploying your application onto server, not the actual development.

Also I'd suggest checking some of [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=deploy%20react%20express%20app%20to%20aws), that are focused on deployment, because that is what I think you are asking, right ?